# Trying to understand how Blender works with Measurements

Tags: modeling

I have been told that in 3D Modeling there are 2 general methods Artistic and the Engineering.

The Artistic method is where the Modeler worries more about how the final project looks good.

The Engineering Modeler generally models real world objects & generally prefers to model the real world measurements.

I’m a self-taught Hobbyist and I know that I’m an Engineering Modeler, I’m trying to make an Old Sealed  Beam Light (using 3 Spheres) but I’m having trouble connecting the reflector to the housing, I can’t match the diameter reflector (6 inches) to housing (6.5 inches) I can’t scale down or extrude up & the edges meet the other.

How I can I ensure my measurements will match each other?

Thanks,

Comment: The most important concept to understand is local and global measurements. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47318/why-do-the-measurements-of-this-object-seem-erroneous/47320#47320 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/103257/why-do-measurements-change-when-switching-from-global-to-local-in-edit-mode/103259#103259

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50850/precision-modeling-how-to-achieve-this-simple-shape/50855#50855 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64038/units-and-dimensions/64046#64046

Comment: As a rule of thumb try to model your objects at the size they would be in the real world. It will matter if you do any kind of physics simulations and can make a huge difference in the intensity needed to light a scene.

Comment: read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64591/what-is-the-exact-purpose-of-object-scale/64594#64594